# Раздача файлов через торрент трекер

Tags: debian, linux

Появилась желание реализовать раздачу файлов, которые хранятся на сервере через приватный торрент трекер. Подскажите чтоб такого почитать для реализации:

1. Создание трекера на debian сервере (сам я нарыл, коекакую инфу, но в друг у вас будет нечто вкуснее)
2. Автоматическое создание торрент-файла из файла который находиться на сервере
3. Файлы с одим именем лежат на сервере, а отдавать его с другим

Возможно ли все это? Сам я только натыкался на статьи о реализации собственного рутрекера, но задача у меня иная. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, поможет ли, но тут [Установка на собственный Linux сервер](http://www.visigod.com/xbt-tracker/installation)

В конце страницы - Using WindowsГугл-переводчик в помощь :)